Python XLSWINGS - Cannot access read-only document
I'm opening an Excel file for data entry using Python Pandas & Xlswings. Everything works fine as long as the Excel file is in an editable state (i.e. not opened by another user).
Firstly, has anyone overcome the 'Cannot access read-only document' when it is being used or locked by another user? or got any tips to deal with this?
Are there any alternative methods to see who has it open so I can notify them to close the file? I'm accessing the file via SharePoint and always assumed dual working was enabled, but clearly not.
